# The proper term for Hosting a P2V image

Tags: hosting, virtual-machines, physical-to-virtual

I have a legacy system that has been converted P2V style to a virtual machine image. What is the proper term for a hosting solution that will use the image I have created?
For some reason I am struggling to find one with Google search.

Private cloud?

Answer (score 1):

VPS can be a good starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server

Generaly speaking, you want a virtual machine. So private cloud can be okay, but this is only a buzzword.

You can also search with "vmware hosting" or "hyper-v hosting" (or "xxxx hosting", replace xxxx with xen, kvm, whatever).

Comment: Thanks, I will start trying some of these search terms and see if I get better results..